# Joint CDF of a random variable $X$ and $X^2$.

Tags: probability

Let X be a continuous random variable with cdf $F$ and pdf $f$.

Then the joint CDF is
$F(a, b) = P(X \le a, X^2 \le b)$

My steps are:

$$\begin{align}
F(a,y) &=P(X \le a , X^2 \le b) \\
&= P(X \le a, -\sqrt{b} \le X \le \sqrt{b} ) \\
&=P(-\sqrt{b} \le X \le \min(\sqrt{b}, a)) \\
&= F(\min(\sqrt{b}, a))-F(-\sqrt{b})
\end{align}$$

I assume $b\ge 0$, otherwise the probability should be $0$.

I can't find a similar problem online, can someone help to check if the process is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: $b$ is automatically greater/equal $0$, since $X \in \mathbb R$